# I am trying to insert data into a table but it gives me "Column not found"

Tags: php, sql, laravel

The error is:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'count_service_email' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `countService`
> (`count_service_email`, `password`, `n_remaining_customers`, `in_day`,
> `service_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (netflix@gmail.com,
> netflix123, 10, true, 1, 2022-08-11 12:19:01, 2022-08-11 12:19:01))"

How can I solve this?

My model:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class CountService extends Model
   {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'countService';

    protected $fillable = [
        'count_service_email',
        'password',
        'n_remaining_customers',
        'in_day',
        'sold_off',
        'service_id'
    ];
  }
```

My migrations:

```
<?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

    class CreateCountServiceTable extends Migration
   {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (!Schema::hasTable('countService')) {
            Schema::create('countService', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('count_service_email')->unique();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->smallInteger('n_remaining_customers');
                $table->boolean('in_day');
                $table->boolean('solt_off');
                $table->smallInteger('service_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('count');
    }
   }
```

My controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'count_service_email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'n_remaining_customers' => 'required',
            'in_day' => 'required',
            'solt_off' => 'required',
            'service_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError('Validation of store count service error.', $validator- 
       >errors());
        }
    
        $count = CountService::create($input);
        return $this->sendResponse(new CountServiceResource($count), 'Count of service 
       create with successfull');
       }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel but where is the piece of code that triggers that particular error message about the `insert` statement?

Comment: You only create the table if it doesn't exist, so maybe that migration didn't run? Check the database directly to see what the definition of the table is, and if the column exists.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius `CountService::create($input);` creates the record. It's a Laravel Eloquent function that inserts everything in the array.

Comment: @aynber - how do i do this verification ? using php artisan migrate ?

Comment: No, you'd log directly into the database, either via command line, or through something like PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @aynber - I will do that and then give you feedback.
now i tried to do it the way you said eliminating the : if (!Schema::hasTable('countService'))  and i run the php artisan migrate and it doesn't work, it returns the following error :  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'countservice' already exists

Comment: "_Base table or view already exists_" means ... the table already exists (most likely without the `count_service_email` column) which is why your migration didn't run. You can use `php artisan migrate:fresh` to **drop all tables** and start migrations from the start. **Attention**: will **drop your tables and any data in it**, make a backup before you run this! (Dont' run this in production ;))

Comment: Your Code seems legit, but have you tried to `dd` on the `$input` request and see if `count_service_email` exists in the query?

Edit: use `$validator` variable instead of `$input`, because the `$validator` holds the validated data, but `$input` holds everything within the request.

Comment: Thanks to all who replied! with your help I solved the problem, the steps to solve the problem was: 
first -> eliminating the : if (!Schema::hasTable('countService'))
second -> change the service_id data type from smallInteger to bigInteger 
third -> run the php artisan migrate:fresh 
and fortunately it worked.

Answer (score 0):

By the error, the it clearly shows that your table doesn't have column `count_service_email` in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who replied! with your help I solved the problem, the steps to solve the problem was: first -> eliminating the : if (!Schema::hasTable('countService')) second -> change the service_id data type from smallInteger to bigInteger third -> run the php artisan migrate:fresh and fortunately it worked